# Equivalent of RouteData.GetRequiredString in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core

I have several HtmlHelper extension methods that I use to create navbar buttons - one is for a context-sensitive help link.  In my extension method I need to know the name of the current controller and action e.g.:

```
var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

What can I use in ASP.NET 5 to get this information since there is no GetRequiredString() method on RouteData anymore?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could create an extension yourself.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
{
    public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static string GetRequiredString(this RouteData routeData, string keyName)
        {
            object value;
            if(!routeData.Values.TryGetValue(keyName, out value))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find key with name '{keyName}'");
            }

            return value?.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks.  BTW if anybody else is doing the same sort of thing, you may also be wondering what to use in place of `UrlHelper.GetContentUrl()`. This is what I'm using - seems to work `var urlHelper = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUrlHelper)) as IUrlHelper; var contentUrl = urlHelper.Content(url);`